# Set width of a Li to whatever is left in its container div

Tags: css, styles

I am facing a `css` problem. I cannot get a `Li` to occupy whatever `width` is left in a `div` How can i possibly do this?

Here is an image for reference:
http://rhythemaggarwal.heliohost.org/login/css/ques.png

Link to my webpage: http://rhythemaggarwal.heliohost.org/login/index.html

Comment: You can paste the relevant HTML/CSS into www.jsfiddle.net to show us a more compact version of your problem. Saves us time and helps us by not having to go to your site and download the entire CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your css as follows:

```
#menu ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and then add

```
#news_link { width: 100%;}
```

that will do what I think you want

Comment: sir it did not do what i wanted to do
See this link.. I did exacly what u said me too:
http://rhythemaggarwal.heliohost.org/login/css/Untitled.png

Comment: thanks a lot sir :)
Now can you please explain what you did here.. Bit new for me.

Comment: basically the display: table-cell tells the browser to lay out the li items as if they where a <td> inside a <table><tr>. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html for the spec on that.

the white-space: nowrap is needed to keep the anchor text from going to 2 lines in the table layout

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `border-right` from `#menu ul li` (change to `border: 0;`) and it works for me

Comment: Thanks for your answer bu i think u dint get my question.. i meant that let say i have a div with width 100 px. out of which 65 px is occupied. Now i want an element in div to automatically fill the rest 45 pixels. I know you would say that why not set the width of the element to 45px. I did but when i zoom in or out it seem to ruin the layout of the page. I want the element to dynamically fill the area i.e 45px accordin to zoom. In short i want it to automatically adjust